# Matching 2 lists in Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am writing an expression to output a filtered entity `List` based on the parameters. One condition I have to check is whether all entries in an input array parameter are present in a related entity. first I tried:

```
((inpArray
     .Intersect(x.B.Select(b=>b.CodeID))
     .Count()==inpArray.Count()) 
|| (inpArray.Count() == 0))
```

This gives me an exception saying comparable types need to be used in `dbIntersect`. So I tried converting both to `Lists` like below:

```
 ((inpList
         .Intersect(x.B.Select(b=>b.CodeID))
         .ToList()
         .Count()==inpList.Count()) 
    || (inpList.Count() == 0))
```

Now the *error* is

> DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection
>   ResultType.

How to best handle the problem?

Many thanks.

**EDIT**
*the above code is part of a predicate argument that I need to pass to a service*

Comment: I was initially using the following code:           
   `( x.B                                                                                                  
      .Any(y => inpArray.Contains(y.CodeID?? 0))                                      
   || (inpArray.Count()==0))`

Comment: This gives a result, but matches all entities which have atleast one array entry which is not needed

Comment: Try `!inpArray.Except(x.B.Select(b=>b.CodeID)).Any()`.

Comment: @Enigmativity  thanks for the reply.. got an error though. 
" DbExceptExpression requires arguments with compatible collection 
 ResultTypes. "

Comment: You need to provide type definitions and probably a [mcve] to get a better answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity the error is gone when I try with input List.. but "Enumeration yields no results".. the input param ls a `byte` list and entity is `IEnumerable<byte>`. I will try to provide an example.

Comment: @Enigmativity  hi your solution works fine!  The mistake was in my implementation.. please submit as answer... many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
!inpArray.Except(x.B.Select(b=>b.CodeID)).Any()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try separating out the list generation:

```
var list1 = inpArray.ToList();
var list2 = x.B.Select(b => b.CodeID).ToList();


if(list1.Count == 0 || list1.Intersect(list2).Count() == list1.Count)
{
    //Your code
}
```

Comment: Hi @SBFrancies.. the above code is part of a predicate argument that I need to pass to a service